# How to use value of JSON object in TypeScript?

Tags: json, typescript

I was wondering how can I use string value of JSON object that I get from input.

```
export class NavComponent implements OnInit {
formVar: FormGroup;
items = [];

constructor(private api: ApiService, private fb: FormBuilder) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formVar = this.fb.group({
    search:''
  });
}

onSubmit(){
  this.api.search(this.formVar.value).subscribe(
    data => {
      this.items = data;
      console.log(this.formVar.value);
    }
  )
 }
}
```

The output for fromVar.value is this:

```
{search: "dfsdf"}
search: "dfsdf"
__proto__: Object
```

but I need only string value inside this object.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
this.formVar.controls['search'].value
```

instead of:

```
this.formVar.value
```